Show which task is currently running in ADO pipeline summary page for a externally managed template
In my Azure Devops pipeline, I am using a template which is stored in a repository where I have only read access (it is managed by another team).
Given template has this structure:
- stage
  - job
    - task1 
    - task2
    - ...
    - task 12

I would like to see on the pipeline summary page which task is currently being run. Unfortunately I am not able to edit the template in order to add any debug. So I cannot add anything like:
echo "##vso[task.setprogress value=0;]Starting task: ${{ parameters.taskName }}"

Currently summary page only shows which stage and job is being run:
How can I add information about which task is currently being run?


What you want is not possible. Considering your screenshot, you would be able to see which task was being run by clicking on "Build" job.

@RuiJarimba Yes if i click on "Build" Job I will be taken to the details page, with console logs. Although I would like to see this in the summary page.


How can I add information about which task is currently being run in pipeline summary page?

It appears that the feature to show which task is currently being run in pipeline summary page does not exist currently. You can only check which task is running by clicking the job to the details page, with console logs. This does not depend on whether you are using a template.
Update:

So I cannot add anything like:
echo "##vso[task.setprogress value=0;]Starting task: ${{ parameters.taskName }}"

When using SetProgress in the task, you can observe that a progress indicator changes with the percentage of completion when the task runs this script in the details page.

However, it will not show in the pipeline summary page.
If you still need the feature, you can request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

I can set the system debug but if there are no meaningfull debug messages in the template.Could you elaborate more about how seting debug to true will help me? Maybe I am missing something

same question goes for "enable system diagnostics", how will this help me to see the currently running task?

Hi @fascynacja, sorry, it seems that I misunderstand this line "Unfortunately, I am not able to edit the template in order to add any debug." I thought you want to check the debug log of the pipeline, so I added the ways to enable debug log in the answer. I will remove this part from the answer.

thank you, I will update my question as well to be more clear

Hi @fascynacja, thanks for your update. I tested the task.setprogress command and found it will not show in the pipeline summary page.

yes it looks it does not solve anything. I read somewhere that it can change the summary page but apparently its not true. Only workaround I found is uploading the summary.md file everytime the task is finished, but still I cannot do it from the template

Hi @fascynacja, yes, if you do not have permission to edit a template, you cannot add any steps to it. The most you can do is add extra steps before or after the template runs. As for showing the exact steps in the summary page, you could make a feature request.
